# Can a virus from a external drive end up on the host computer?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, virus

If I connnect a external drive to a computer that has viruses, and somehow these viruses get on the external drive, like someone copying infected files on it or whatever, and then I connect this drive to a clean computer, can that computer get the virus? I mean just by connecting the drive. I know that the drive has infected files so obviously I won't run any program from it, but I still need to connect the drive so I can erase the files. I also know that having a anti-virus installed would be the safest method but I'd like to avoid going trough the process of installing annoying anti-virus software if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a virus on a flash drive run itself without autorun?](http://superuser.com/questions/393027/can-a-virus-on-a-flash-drive-run-itself-without-autorun), [How to be safe plugging in an infected USB?](http://superuser.com/questions/605844/how-to-be-safe-plugging-in-an-infected-usb)

Comment: yes, if the malware can link into the USB autorun configuration. I had a box I slicked three times trying to get rid of a rootkit that kept reappearing. It took that long for me to realize that on the first try, the box infected my tools thumbdrive, and every time I rebuilt it and went to install software off the usb, that I was reinfecting it all over again. For Trojans you have to avoid executing the exe, and thats easy enough, but for worms and rootkits, just pluging it in is dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have antivirus, you can indeed be infected by simply plugging a disk into a machine providing that you have autorun enabled.

Autorun is a function within windows which will scan particular files/locations on any disck (external drive, DVD, CD, USB etc) for a "default" program to run on discovering the disk.  A typical example of this is the auto-launching of a software installer when you insert a software CD/DVD/USB.

If a virus can infect that file on a non-clean machine, then it will auto-execute and infect your PC simply by plugging the disk in.

If you disable AutoRun within windows, you should be a bit safer - but nothing will be as safe as running good quality AV.  External Disks are far from the only attack vector:

1. Opening unrecognised email attachments/loading word/excel/powerpoint files with embedded virus-riddled macros can infect you
2. Viruses can be embedded in PDF Files
3. Visiting an infected website can infect your computer
4. Visiting a website running Flash (which seems to develop a new exploit about twice a day!) can get you infected by a third party site even if the website you are visiting itself is clean.

Some general rules to try and minimise your exposure if you are planning to NOT run AV:

- Don't open attachments from people you don't know/trust
- Open anything you are unsure about on a VM/sandbox to reduce the risk to your host PC
- Keep windows fully patches to reduce attack vectors
- Try to keep the PC off the internet
- If you can't keep the machine off the net, run a good secure browser, an ad-blocker and a good script blocking Addon
- Don't Install Flash.
- Disable AutoRun for Windows
- Run a non-admin account for day to day work

A far better solution would be to install a good quality non-intrusive AV platform - there are some good ones out there, but if you are determined to NOT run AV - try and play safely.

Comment: It is important to note that as a general rule, every malware protection system can be expected to miss between 20% and 60% of all in-the-wild malware at any given time. most of the better products hover around the 20% line.

Comment: Absolutely Frank - I agree completely... by goo quality, I meant good qualiy detection, not well known though!  Even so, they're a best-effort endevour on the behalf of the vendor and arent guaranteed protection from everything.  After all, the virus needs to be in the wild and infecting people before the virus-fighters can even get their hands on it and find a way to fight it.

Comment: I disabled autorun from a long time, and I won't be opening any files from the drive. Just straight erase all files

Comment: You should be safe... but if you want to be belt-n-braces super-safe - get hold of a Live CD (Linux bootable Operating system) and nuke the disk from outside of your main operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. Not all types of malware will replicate themselves like this, but many will. Answer is a definite yes.